# Show figure in input dialog box matlab

Tags: matlab, input, figure, dialog

i would like to know how i can add a figure to my inputdlg() in matlab. I would like to show a small figure i created to help with filling in the input.
This is my input dialog i have.

```
    prompt       = {'Length:'};
    dlg_title    = 'Straight Duct specs';
    num_lines    = 1;
    SDelements   = {'0'};
    Straightduct = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,SDelements);
```

Perhaps some one can show me the way?
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither the built-in `inputdlg` nor the more powerful user-contributed [`inputsdlg`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25862-inputsdlg-enhanced-input-dialog-box-v2-0-4) natively offer the possibility to add axes (and thus images) to the dialog window.

Your best guess is to create your own dialog window via [GUIDE](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/creating_guis/confirmation-dialog-box-guide.html), or to modify `inputsdlg`.

Comment: Oh allright, that's what i had figured from the mathworks info. thank you for the confirmation. Would you reckon it would be possible to use the regular mmessage box as an input box? or at least couple that together with an inputdlg? Make it show the drawing and dissapear once you've entered the required inputs.

Comment: @user3049970:I suggest you create your own dialog. This way, you can most easily define the callback of the edit text field that will control the presence of the picture.